# Bind function to a button from a view js file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This class is located in ShowResults.js which is a view

```
class ShowResults{    
         async function getHtml(){
            return "<button type="submit" onclick="this.doThis()" class="btn btn-info" id="btn-id">Add</button>"
            }
         doThis(e){
            console.log("button pressed")
            }
    }
```

this view is called in index.js

```
 let view=new ShowResults();
 document.getElementById("app").innerHTML= await view.getHtml();
```

The problem i have is that the button doesn't call the function and I get a Reference Error. The view itself is rendered properly.
Thank you

Comment: If the accepted answer solved your issue (or helped solving it), please, also up vote it.

Comment: @emi I have up voted it but, my reputation isn't high enough for my vote to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind functions in components defined in plain strings. You'll need to create a real DOM object and assign an event listener to it:

```js
class ShowResults{    
         async function getHtml(){
            const componentStr = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn-id">Add</button>';
            const temp = document.createElement('template');
            temp.innerHTML = componentStr;
            const component = temp.content.firstChild;
            component.addEventListener('click', this.doThis.bind(this));
            return component;
            }
         doThis(e){
            console.log("button pressed")
            }
    }
```

And then:

```js
 let view=new ShowResults();
 document.getElementById("app").appendChild(await view.getHtml());
```

#### Note

Here, `async` and `await` keywords are not needed, unless HTML string is being fetched or something else that really needs it.